# Are my Bluetooth roles conflicting?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Im currently making an app that uses Bluetooth to advertise and also to scan that advertisement.  This way if I have the app on two different phones then one could be the peripheral and the other could be the central. Do I need to divide these functions up?  Basically I have the peripheral manager open in the viewDidLoad and the protocols and all that called after so basically right when i open it up it starts advertising.  In another implementation file I have the same thing but for the central manager.  So the central manager starts up in the viewDidLoad(but different file) as well and then all the protocols are called and then it starts scanning.

My question is:

Is it okay to have these roles implemented at the same time, in the same way but in different implementation files or do I need to have separate states for both?

I dont know if this relates, but all my code checks out, however, when i try to run it it doesnt get past the linking stage and it gives me this error:

Apple Mach-O linker error

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to scan on a `CBCentralManager` and advertise on a `CBPeripheralManager` at the same exact time. Your problem is that you haven't added the `CoreBluetooth.framework` most likely (usually the source of linker errors). Also I recommend implementing the `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheralManager` inside their own singleton files (not necessary but it's cleaner).